# Get first output from STDOUT and terminate process

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to scan a single QR-code and return the result to STDOUT. I discovered [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/), which is a nice little program that almost does everything I need.

```
$ zbarcam --raw
```

scans QR-codes with the PC camera and returns the data to STDOUT. However, it does not terminate. The program scans multiple codes and returns them. It only stops by closing the video window or sending an interrupt.

How do I in general only get the first output from STDOUT, terminate the process, and then send the received output to STDOUT again in the command line? I probably need a Bash script for that right?

Comment: doesn't `-1, --oneshot` option terminate zbar?

Comment: There is not an option like this.

Comment: seems to be introduced in [0.23.1](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar/releases/tag/0.23.1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`, and assuming there is only one line to read (the qrcode does not have embedded newlines), you can try

```bsh
(echo $BASHPID; exec zbarcam --raw ) | 
(read pid; IFS= read -r line; kill -hup "$pid"; printf "%s\n" "$line")
```

The `$BASHPID` is because `$$` does not change in subshells, so is the parent shell pid. The `IFS= read -r` should retain backslash and leading spaces in the input.